# Access `.next/server` on Vercel. It works on Netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

How to access `.next/server` on Vercel when running `build:rss` script:

```json
{
 "export": "next export",
 "build": "next build && npm run export && npm run build:rss",
 "build:rss": "node ./.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js",
 "start": "next start",
}
```

Vercel throws error:

```sh
> node ./.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js
15:14:05.786 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
15:14:05.786 throw err;
15:14:05.786 ^
15:14:05.786 Error: Cannot find module '/vercel/workpath0/.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js'
15:14:05.786 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
15:14:05.786 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
15:14:05.786 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
15:14:05.786 at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
```

whereas Netlify works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change `server` to `serverless` in the `build:rss` script to make it work :)